# Google Drive API / Storing a file property as a number instead of string

Tags: python, google-drive-api, metadata

Given the `files` [reference page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) of Google Drive API, it appears that metadata that can be added using 'properties' can only be strings.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": string,
  "name": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "description": string,
  "trashingUser": {  },
  "trashedTime": datetime,
  "parents": [string],
  "properties": { (key): string },
}
```

I have however need to store a timestamp, which is basically an int.

When [querying](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms), I would like to be able to select all files with a timestamp lower or larger than a given value.

Please, is there any way to achieve this?
If this new property 'timestamp' is a string, how using `>` or `<` operators?

Thank you very much for your help.
Have a good day,
Bests,

PS: I am using Google Drive API python client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- In your situation, there are the files which have `properties` with `timestamp` as a key and the number value in your Google Drive.
- You want to retrieve the files by comparing with the value of `timestamp` using a value.
- From `a timestamp, which is basically an int`, the value of `timestamp` is the unix time.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Python.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following answer.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, in order to search the files using `properties` of the search query of the files.list method in Drive API, it is required to use `properties has {key='timestamp' and value='###'}`. In this case, the value is required to be the string type. And also, unfortunately, for example, the files with `timestamp` in `properties` cannot be directly retrieved by `properties has {key='timestamp'}`. It seems that this is the current specification. So unfortunately, in the current stage, the files, that you want to retrieve, cannot be directly retrieved using the search query.

So in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve all files in Google Drive using the files.list method in Drive API.
2. Retrieve the files which have `timestamp` as a key in `properties`. At that time, the value of `timestamp` is compared with an inputted value.

When a sample script is prepared from above workaround, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
compareValue = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 12).timestamp()  # Please input the date value you want to compare.

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
fileList = []
pt = ""
while True:
    res = service.files().list(pageSize=1000, pageToken=pt if pt != "" else "", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, properties)").execute()
    files = res.get('files', [])
    filesWithProp = [f for f in files if f.get('properties') and f.get('properties').get('timestamp') and int(f.get('properties').get('timestamp')) > compareValue]
    fileList.extend(filesWithProp)
    pt = res.get('nextPageToken')
    if not pt:
        break
print(fileList)
```

- In the current script, the newer files than `compareValue` can be retrieved.
- When you modified from `int(f.get('properties').get('timestamp')) > compareValue` to `int(f.get('properties').get('timestamp')) < compareValue`, the older files than `compareValue` can be retrieved.

#### Note:

- **In this sample script, the key and value of `properties` are `timestamp` and the unix time, respectively. So please be careful this.**
- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to get the file metadata using Drive API with googleapis for Python.
- If the files you want to retrieve are put in the specific folder, you can also use the query parameter like `'folderId' in parents`. By this, the process cost can be reduced.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, thank you very much for this very neat answer. I am a bit sad there is no workaround that would enable to do the comparison on Google Drive side, ie, that would avoid having multiple queries to get the full list of files.
Buf fair enough, congratulation for this magnificent answer :)!
Thanks again!